# Android app has warning message of not responding

Tags: android

Either you can Force close or Wait.

If I press the Wait then everything will be fine. But how do I disable this annoying message, I don't think something wrong but probably takes some more times to init and runs the App, the wait time bit long.

Comment: instead of disabling the message, it is better to put initialization into the separate thread. So that application's UI thread will not be blocked for too long. While it is init-ing - you can display some progress animation. This is a good practice of designing your app. Nobody likes applications that don't respond timely on touches or so.

Comment: Now how could we disable this slow, blocking, useless, nonsense, message for ALL apps, would be a good subject, disable that obnoxity from the system itself.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what's happening is that you are running a really long computation (for example, fetching something from the internet) on the UI thread. You can get rid of that message by running that computation in a separate thread.

For more information on how to do this, you can refer to this as a starting point: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: How does this help anyone? This is useless for non-developers.

Comment: "I have this problem, do you know how I could obtain this solution?". "You should do this other thing to fix your code once and for all". Nice, but it's not my code! I know that I shouldn't run long computations on the main thread but it looks like the Nextcloud devs don't care! So? Do you have a solution for this or should I completely rewrite the Nextcloud client for Android?